# Identify the completion of for loop in swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift2

i am having the following for loop,

```
for (key, value) in changedDataDictionary {
    // here i want to identify last key and value
}
```

I want to identify the execution of last object/ completion of the for loop

It may be very silly question, but i dont have any idea about that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as a dictionary isn't sorted, this doesn't make sense... there is no DEFINED order

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Please add some context. What are you trying to achieve with the last object iterated on?

Comment: I want to identify the completion of for loop

Comment: @Venkat Do you mean completion before handling the last element? If you want to detect completion after handling the last element, just put your code after the loop.

Comment: The line below the closing brace of the for loop will be executed when the loop completes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work in general

```
var index: Int = 0

for (key, value) in changedDataDictionary {
   index += 1;
   if (index == changedDataDictionary.count) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Note that a dictionary doesn't have a defined order so the last element will always be a different one and usually there is a better solution than using a tracking index.

If you just want to identify last key and element, you can also:

```
var lastKey: KeyType? = nil
var lastElement ValueType? = nil

for (key, value) in changedDataDictionary {
   lastKey = key;
   lastValue = value;
}

// do something with last key and value
```

Comment: or you could just execute something after the loop considering dictionaries have no order....

Comment: hey @sulthan!  in the first code passage I could call that *count* or perhaps *number* since it is a "human" number (runs from 1 to the amount).  We reserve "index" for "computer" numbers (runs from 0 to the amount less one).  Just a thought !!  cheers